# Scraping website: not able to click a button

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape this website
https://www.underarmour.com/en-us/womens/apparel/sports-bras?lsg=4eab83ec-bc9d-495a-bf57-7b49b43c7560

use US as country

I am trying to scrape all the links attached to images.

But I am not able to click the LOAD MORE button no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Selenium too with PhantomJS.

You should be able to find a workaround the AJAX id problem, many sites use generated id but that element will still have the same position so selecting it via css would be an option I guess. I have had this problem before and what I would do is getting the html with selenium then using lxml/cssselect (python) I would find the buttons to click and then I would click them "injecting" js code on the active browser, but I suppose you could skip the python part.